# Are executables created as window service hard to be memory edited?

Tags: c#

If an executable is made to run as a window service and someones tries to edit its memory or inject some code into, this becomes harder?

I mean , since the process is shown only in the services list rather than the processlist it means that it is harder to hook it and there must be other methods of editing the memory/hooking the process .

Thanks in advance,

Comment: A windows service often runs under a more locked-down account (commonly known as a "service account" - see "Principle of Least Privilege"). However, this is a best practice, rather than a required rule. Apart from that, it's the same as just running an executable in terms of your question.

Comment: A service is still a running process and a user with sufficient privileges on the machine will be able to see it and/or terminate it.

Comment: I'm not talking about the visibility of the service nor the capability of terminating it. The idea is that , if someone wants to inject an external dll into it or edit the memory of the executable while running , is that possible?

Comment: Of course that's possible, the user of the machine stays in control over the machine.  And can give himself any rights required to mess with any program or alter the security context in which the program runs.

Comment: @Alex I think it would be best if you post a new question (and add a link in the comments of this one so that we see it) where you describe the specific issue that prompted you to ask this question - I suspect that this question is not necessarily related to the issue you face...